# How did so many helicopters fit on deck?

Tags: kong-skull-island, monsterverse

In the starting scene of the movie *Kong Skull Island* we can see a whole bunch of helicopters being deployed off the deck of a freighter. As I count there are:
9x UH-1 Iroquois (main deck),
1x CH-47 Chinook (front deck), and
1x CH-53 Sea Stallion (rear deck).

[image: Multiple helicopters in flight]

plus supposedly 3 more UH-1s for the final rendezvous (These don't seem like a problem as a later scene shows them parked in the rear hanger). Those 9 are supposed to fit on the main deck and they probably would if it was for storage. But considering the space needed for the blades to rotate when they are turned on, is it really practical?

[image: 3 Helicopters on deck]

Now its obvious they had to take turns to take off, but if the deck is completely occupied at first that won't also work. The model of the ship and its specs could also she some light on the situation.

Comment: I think this one gets put in the **movie mistakes** column. There are 5 UH-1s on the main deck. Someone got a little enthusiastic in cloning choppers I suspect.

Comment: Even if they *extras* were in the hold (and there doesn't seem to have been room) there is no mechanism to get them on to the deck.

Comment: There appear to have been quite a few errors - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3731562/goofs

Comment: As you  note, there is a shot of the rear, which shows 3 more. I took a quick __[screenshot](http://imgur.com/BzqCOF7)__. Maybe there is an elevator in the back.

Comment: @Paulie_D This ship seems to carry more helicopters than an assault carrier, maybe U.S navy should consider deploying cargo ships instead of those :D

Comment: Is it possible there were multiple carrier ships?

Answer (score 2):

### Possibly lined up, with their rotors folded

The video below shows multiple helicopters landing on an aircraft carrier:

At the start of the video we can see on the right that some helicopters are waiting, with their rotors folded, in a similar way to this:

[image: Cobra helicopters on deck]

It is possible that this method was used by the crew to store multiple helicopters during the voyage.

Providing enough space is left to allow one to take off, the others could then be moved into position one at a time, and have ample room to take off.